# Add specific color to some of children nodes in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

I have some nodes which are children of parents (Group of nodes). Is it possible to override the Backgraound-color for some children?

I could only override the normal nodes color like this:

```
cy.nodes('[id = "start"]').style('background-color', '#FBFBFB');
```

Thanks in advance.

```
[
  {
    "style": [
      {
        "selector": "node",
        "css": {
          "shape": "roundrectangle",
          "height": "40px",
          "background-color": "#58D68D",
          "label": "data(id)",
          "text-valign": "center",
          "border-width": "2",
          "border-color": "black"
        }
      },
      {
        "selector": ":parent",
        "css": {
          "background-opacity": "0.333",
          "text-halign": "center",
          "text-valign": "top"
        }
      },
]
]
}
```

Comment: could you post a sample of the html in question?

Comment: Hi @MarioPerez I have added an html example may be this will help find an answer.

Comment: @Ahmed you didn't add HTML. You added badly indented and invalid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just specify the color of nodes when you initialize them:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        "shape": "roundrectangle",
        "height": "40px",
        "background-color": function(node) {
          if (node.data("colored"))
            return "#FBFBFB";
          else
            return "#58D68D";
        },
        "label": "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "border-width": "2",
        "border-color": "black"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':parent',
      css: {
        "background-opacity": "0.333",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "text-valign": "top"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        label: "\u2B24",
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "target-arrow-shape": "data(arrow)"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0",
          colored: true,
          parent: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1",
          colored: false,
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2",
          colored: true,
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3",
          colored: true,
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4",
          colored: false,
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5",
          colored: false,
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "concentric",
    minNodeSpacing: 140
  }
}));
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.cxtmenu-disabled {
  opacity: 0.333;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.10.1/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan T.  Is it possible to make minus/plus-icon for the group of nodes always visible for all parents without crossover the mouse ?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to? Is that a part of your question above? I can't find any group icon in the code you provided.

Comment: Here is the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557799/keep-icon-minus-plus-always-visible-on-the-parent-nodes-in-cytoscape-js) @Stephan T.

Comment: That question is closed due to the lack of clarity, please post your code (as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), after your edit I can try helping you with that feature.